# Inserting a background image into a Header

Tags: html, css, header, background-image

I was trying to insert a background image to act as a backdrop for my Header. It went well if I were to use background color to act as the backdrop for the Header

```
h2 {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

However, it does not went well for the background Image....

Code:

```
h2 {
    background-image: url("gear.png");
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Can someone please guide me towards the solution? I highly appreciate your help. Thx

Comment: Define "not went well".

Comment: can you show also the HTML?

Comment: is the path to the image correct? inspect with firebug.

Comment: Is `gear.png` in the same directory as your CSS? Otherwise you need to make sure your path to the image is correct. That'd be the first place I'd look, without seeing your HTML.

Comment: yea i did put it into the same directory folder with my html folder. By "not went well" means that the position of the image does not fit in well, meaning it only displays partially on the part of header instead of fitting into it.

Answer (score 0):

See [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) and [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).

```
h2 {
    background-image: url("gear.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: The background styling can also be short handed to `background:url(gear.png) no-repeat top left;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to wrap your h2 in a div. It would look and be styled a lot better.

```
<div style="padding:15px;background-image:url('gear.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<h2>This is your header</h2>
</div>
```

Also make sure that the image is in the same folder as your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

You can add background as h2 background:

```
h2 {
    background-image: url("http://www.pawelkaim.com/img/videoEditingIreland.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}
```

But this may not be the best solution.

I recommend you to create extra div and put a h2 tag inside:

```
<div class="bg"> <h1> Hello world</h1></div>

.bg{
    background-image: url("http://www.pawelkaim.com/img/videoEditingIreland.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

In this case you can adjust width and height values of your div to achieve best look. Also you can position your heading with CSS.

```
h1{
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PawelK/H8pG9/1/)